# Adding multiple labels to an OWL class (similar to SKOS:altLabel)

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api, iri, skos

I am editing ontologies for a project in `JAVA` with `org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology`. I need to find a solution about adding multiple labels to an owl class. 
For any class `c` from OWL-API, I can get its label via `c.getIRI()`. But how can I add the second label to this class?

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
    private static void addMultipleLabel() {
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();

    IRI iri_1 = IRI.create("my_first_label");
    IRI iri_2 = IRI.create("my_second_label");
    OWLClass myClass = factory.getOWLClass(iri_1);
    // how to assign also iri_2 to myClass

}
```

I found in SKOS, there is a possibility to add several labels for a class. But, using `SKOS:altLabel` requires that I define my owl class as a SKOS concept, which it put me in a challenge to change all my used models in the project.

Is there any clue, **how can I add multiple labels for an OWL-API Class**?

Thanks in advance for your suggestion and help.

Comment: That is not a label for the class, it is the class IRI. Only one iri can be defined for a class.

Comment: Multiple labels are possible creating annotation assertion axioms that use rdfs:label or skos:altLabel as annotation property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ignazio, 
 so I correct it like this:

```
    private static void addMultipleLabel() throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLOntology myOnt = manager.createOntology(IRI.create("C:\\LOCAL_FOLDER_\\ontName.owl"));

    IRI iri_1 = IRI.create("my_first_label");
    IRI iri_2 = IRI.create("my_second_label");
    OWLClass myClass = factory.getOWLClass(iri_1);

    OWLAnnotationProperty labels = factory.getRDFSLabel();

    OWLAnnotation pA1 = factory.getOWLAnnotation(labels, iri_1);
    OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom myAxiom1 = factory.getOWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom(myClass.getIRI(), pA1);
    manager.addAxiom(myOnt, myAxiom1);

    OWLAnnotation pA2 = factory.getOWLAnnotation(labels, iri_2);
    OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom myAxiom2 = factory.getOWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom(myClass.getIRI(), pA2);
    manager.addAxiom(myOnt, myAxiom2);

}
```

Comment: Note that you're creating IRI objects that are not absolute IRIs (no protocol at the beginning, e.g., `urn:` or `http:`). This might create unexpected results later. Do you want these to be IRIs or do you need just strings as labels? If the second, use `OWLLiteral` instances instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, you are right. Here I show a sample code, but indeed, in my project, I do not create a new class with new IRI. I use other existing classes with other existing IRI of those classes from well-known ontologies. So, my existing classes have a correct IRI (starting with `http:` ). Thanks also for mentioning using `OWLLiteral`.